# Significant predictors in multiple linear regression became non-significant in multiple logistic regression

Tags: regression, logistic, multiple-regression, regression-coefficients

I have several continuous predictor variables (A, B, C) and a continuous outcome variable X.

Some of the X values include NAs, because they were below the instrument detection limit. So I figured that I could either 1) treat the outcome variable as a continuous variable, treating the NAs as zeros (since they're below the detection level), or 2) treat the outcome variable as a binary variable, treating the NAs as zeros and non-NA values as ones (if I place more importance on whether X is above or below the detection limit rather than the exact values of X).

So following option 1, I did a multiple linear regression between the predictor and outcome variables, and found a significant positive correlation between X and A, but not between X and B/C.

Then following option 2, I did a multiple logistic regression, and I found no significant correlation between X and A but between X and B/C.

I'm struggling to understand why the significance of predictors change so dramatically. Am I somehow weakening the positive correlation between outcome X and predictor A by ignoring the exact values of X and treating them as either 0 or 1?

Comment: You could use some sort of hurdle model - what's the probability it was detectable, followed by if it was detectable, what is the value.

Comment: @JeremyMiles Thank you for the suggestion, from a quick search, it sounds like a combination of the two options I had in mind. I'm still confused as to why the linear and logistic regression results differ. Would you think that comparing these two regression results are meaningless because choosing these models (over the hurdle model, for instance) was a wrong choice?

Comment: You say that they change in significance, but that's not often interesting. If a p-value changes from 0.06 to 0.04 that's probably not meaningful. Even if the underlying model is the same, then you expect a dichotomous variable to have less power, and therefore less likely to be significant.

Comment: I'd be more surprised if the results were the same.